# Assign a dynamic string to the ID of an element

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to assign a dynamic string to the ID of an element.
Here's how my input element is:

```
<input id = 'ac'+ @item.index />
```

notice, I am assigning 'ac' + @item.index

@item.index is the dynamic part, it is an integer.

I can assign @item.index and it works, however, when I try to combine the
string 'ac' to @item.index, it does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using an [explicit code nugget](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/16/asp-net-mvc-3-implicit-and-explicit-code-nuggets-with-razor.aspx). Basically just wrap it in brackets. You'll also want quotes around your attribute value.

Try this

```
<input id="ac@(item.index)" />
```

Comment: 'ac' + @(item.index) gives <input id='ac' + 0; / >

Comment: <input id="@("ac" + item.index)";  this did it for me, I must thank Brandon and Jordan because I used their ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the integer to a string then combining them

*Edit* sorry the first one I posted was was for Java, here's the javscript

'ac' + @item.index.toString();

Comment: 'ac' + @item.index.toString(); gives <input id='ac' + '0'; />

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `ac` is going to be a plain string in html. So is what follows it (the +).

Instead, you should just plug it right in (remember it will literally write right there)

```
<input id = 'ac@(item.index)' />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `string.Format` here

```
   <input id='@string.Format("ac{0}", item.index)' />
```

This way it would be crystal clear what exactly you are doing.